# Custom OAuth2 consent flow

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I'm building a service provider application where users are supposed to be able to share their data with a third party application using OAuth2 and OpenID Connect.

The standard OAuth2 consent flow authorize scopes (which attributes / roles to share).
However, since attributes could consist of multiple values, we would also like to allow the user to select which value/s to share.

So my question is, should I replace the whole OAuth2 consent flow with a custom one where OAuth2 scopes are more or less replaced with explicit attribute key/value pairs?
It feels a bit weird to remove such a core component of OAuth2 as scopes, what do you think? Any other suggestions?

I'm currently trying out spring authorization server for customizing the consent flow (since Keycloak that we're currently using doesn't seem to be that flexible with the consent logic).

I think that replacing the standard consent flow in spring authorization server would require rewrites of both OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService, OAuth2AuthorizationConsentAuthenticationProvider as well as all the OAuth2...AuthenticationProvider classes that are used for authentication in order to forward consent to the new consent flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the official [custom consent](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/custom-consent-authorizationserver) sample! This sample demonstrates a custom consent screen without replacing the built-in components for handling submission of the consent screen and saving user consent in the `OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService`.

In particular, [these lines](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/blob/3f5e7c793bbc9875d2753fb5427423d553dd9b16/samples/custom-consent-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L59-L61) configure the consent page, and [this controller endpoint](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/blob/3f5e7c793bbc9875d2753fb5427423d553dd9b16/samples/custom-consent-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/web/AuthorizationConsentController.java#L50-L54) implements the logic for building a custom consent screen, which can be whatever you need for your application.

If you are wanting to customize what is mapped from the consent screen to the saved authorization, you would customize the [OAuth2 Authorization Endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/protocol-endpoints.html#oauth2-authorization-endpoint) with an `authorizationRequestConverter()`. Scopes are simply stored as "authorities", so you can instead (or in addition) store anything you want.

To customize the access token (JWT) that is produced as a result of this consent and authorization, provide a `OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext>` as in the example [OAuth2TokenCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer) from the reference documentation.

Comment: How does the app knows which path to redirect, after the user went through the consent screen?

Comment: @Holm The `redirect_uri` from the authorize request is used to redirect back to the client with the `code` (authorization code) parameter.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the exact purpose of scope: contain user consent on what data (attributes names) a specific client can access on their behalf. Usually, to ease user selection and software maintenance, the attributes granularity in scope selection is not the same as internal data model (for instance a `contact` scope could represent phone, country, city, zipcode and street columns in database)

As roles, groups, permissions or whatever should be mapped to Spring authorities are not specified by Oauth2 nor OpenID, authorization-servers use private claims to store this data (and usually not scope). If you are used to Keycloak, you should have noticed that roles are put by default in `realm_access.roles` and `resource_access.{client-id}.roles`.  Other authorization-servers will use other private claim(s).

Simply put, roles (or groups or permissions or whatever you want to call it) define what a specific **user** can do in the system when scope should contain which resources a specific **client** is allowed to access on behalf of that user.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand.
Actually, it's mainly the oidc id-token values that we would like to control.
The user should e.g. be able to have multiple email addresses in our system, but when they login to a third party system using our service provider they should be able to select 1 email address to share with that specific third party while sharing another email address with another third party.

Comment: So we would not like to share access to the attribute itself, we would basically like to build a new user profile customized for each third party.

Comment: In OAuth2, users do not login to a third party system. They do login on an **authorization-server** and grant scopes to each **client** (potentially third party application) to allow it to manipulate resources on **resource-servers**. In your case, the resource-sever also is the authorization-server and resource is the ID-token content. Just have authorization-server look at scope before issuing ID-token, just as any resource-server should do when user can scope the data per client.

Comment: Ok, but how do the user specify which email to share in the consent flow as a scope when scope is just a string and not a key value?
The resource in our case will probably be the third party applications resource server.
They will most likely have their own authorization server and use our auhorization server as service provider.
So the users are primarily stored on our side, then when they sign in to their authorization server they need to sign in to our application and share the data they want with the third partys auhtorization server.

Comment: So their authorization server would contain a user as well which contain a subset of the data of the user in our system.

Comment: @user3677636 If every application has its own authorizaion server, you don't need your own. I can't see any reason. If you want to use a centralized user directory, you could use LDAP, Active directory, ... There you could configure which system could see any email address.

Comment: Hmm, ok..
But we still want them to use our authentication method every time they login.
So every time they login to the third party application they use our login method (PKI with 2 factor) and are able to update the values.

Comment: Would that indicate that we need our own authorization server?

Comment: My boss is the visionary and he's not technical, but he have done this before and are trying to explain the technical bits that he don't fully understand, so sometimes it gets a bit confusing for me..

Comment: I guess I could make my own consent flow that uses scopes as usual as well as builds a new user bound to that client and when they accept the consent they also update their client-user.
Then the id-token is generated based on the scopes and the client-user attributes?

Comment: You just need to expose a user-info endpoint on a resource-server of your own and a UI ("admin" client) to control what is displayed to each client. [Openid defines only one e-mail](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Standard Claims). If you define a maximum count of emails in your system, you can solve your problem with scopes (`email`, `alt_email1`, `alt_email2`, etc.), otherwise you'll have to implement your own logic to fit squares in round holes (map non standard data to OpenID claims)

Comment: If you want to customize both user-info and ID-token on Keycloak, you can use a "mapper", but you might have to link Keycloak to your own user database to have several emails... [sample mapper](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/proxies-Keycloak-mapper). It adds a private claim, but could alter a standard claim as well)

Comment: @ch4mp hmm, ok..
I'm not only thinking of the standard openid claims, we want to be able to share any attribute this way.

Comment: "any other attributes" are OpenID private claims.

Comment: The end goal is that a user should be able to have multiple emails (or other attributes) and during the consent flow they should be able to select which email is shared with the third party

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251035/discussion-between-user3677636-and-ch4mp).

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add some use-case based notes on the parties involved, and how consent is meant to work.

**CLIENT**

The client app simply redirects with a scope parameter. It is possible to send a claims parameter but that is rarely used. A scope might be `profile` and be composed of `name` and `date of birth` claims.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

This presents the requested information in a consent screen. The most flexible way to do this is to present the claims, eg as checkboxes. Some claims, eg name, might be marked as required and use a disabled checkbox. Others, eg date of birth, can be optional. The user might deselect the latter claim and it would then not be included in tokens issued.

**CUSTOMIZING CONSENT**

Ideally no customization should be needed to achieve the above, which should work out of the box. This may not be the case for Spring though. It is valid to customize consent though. An interesting case where this is done is in Open Banking, where a user can consent to payment of a runtime amount of money:

```
I consent to pay company X £100 for product Y from account Z
```